# CSS modal doesn't take parent's full height

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I want the popup modal to take full height, but it doesn't when there's some overflow.

The popup is shown once the user clicks a card. Below, there're images of the behaviors if the user clicks a cards when there's no scroll vs when there's scroll.

The parent `section` is set to **relative** and the child modal is set to **absolute**.

I'm using TailwindCSS and VueJS frameworks.

### Parent

```
<section id="dashboard" class="flex flex-col relative w-full h-full">
    <!-- Cards and stuff -->
    <div class="flex flex-col flex-auto w-full min-h-min px-5 py-10">
        ...
    </div>
    <!-- Modal popup -->
    <SummaryPopUp v-if="popup" @popUp="toggle_popup"/>
</section>
```

### Child [Popup]

```
<div class="absolute flex flex-col w-full h-full justify-center place-items-center bg-gray-400">
    <!-- Close button -->
    <button type="button">
    </button>
</div>
```

#### Parent height vs Child modal height

[image]

[image]

#### Not scrolled vs Scrolled

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you already tried giving your modal `w-screen h-screen` or positioning it with `absolute inset-0`?

Comment: @EdLucas Yes I have, it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you are not using `position: fixed;` instead of absolute ?

Since modal is a popup, there is no reason for it to be absolute to anything, since it will overlay the screen and in your case, cover everything.

Comment: Actually, there's also some stuff on the right side too. But I just want the model to show and cover that area. `position: fixed`  won't do